# How to pass an NSError object from a background thread to the main thread without violating memory management rules?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I am doing numerous operations such as retrieval from web, importing, file operations, etc. in a background thread.  Each operation is called using `NSInvocationOperation`.  Once each operation is complete, the background thread operation calls `performSelectorOnMainThread:`.  The model I am using is for the background thread to call `operationSucceeded` or `operationFailed` depending on the success or failure of the background operation.

When I call `operationFailed`, I want to pass an `NSError` object back to the main thread so that the thread can take any appropriate action with the UI.  In the case of the failure, for example, I may or may not want to display an error message to the user.

The question is: How can I send the `NSError` back to the main thread without running into memory management concerns?  Each operation that is called using `NSInvocationOperation` has it's own local `NSAutoreleasePool` per Apple requirements.  When I pass back an `NSError` object using `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:error`, doesn't the local `NSAutoreleasePool` release the `NSError` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. As is explained in the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-CJBEHAEF), `performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(foo:) withObject:obj` retains `obj` until the selector is executed.

Comment: Ah... sometimes I feel so dumb.  It's right there in front of me.  "This method retains the receiver and the arg parameter until after the selector is performed."  That makes me feel like I did when I was a kid.  I would look in my drawer for a particular pair of socks and couldn't find them.  But, my mom could come in and see them right on top.  Thank you for the assist.

Comment: No problem at all. That happens to everyone. Eventually you'll be like your mom in this programming situation!